# Карта в диалоговом окне

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout-inflater

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы `findFragmentById(R.id.map);` брал ресурс из `layout` подключенный в `LayoutInflater`.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.address, null);

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Address");
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();

            Button close = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
            Button save = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                    }
                });

        }


    });
```